# pandoc on Ubuntu can't use beamer

Tags: 11.10, presentation, slideshow, pandoc

I'm using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) to author slides. I'd like to see how the beamer PDF output looks, but I'm getting an error:

```
$ pandoc -t beamer talk.txt -o talk.pdf
pandoc: Unknown writer: beamer
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question. [beamer support was added in pandoc 1.9](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/releases.html) (2012-02-05), but my Ubuntu 11.10 desktop has pandoc 1.8.1.1.

I updated pandoc as follows:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove pandoc
sudo apt-get install cabal-install
cabal update
cabal install pandoc
```

Notice the last two commands do *not* use `sudo`.